# JavaScript undefined?

Tags: javascript

UPDATED CODE

CURRENT ERROR: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id_cursa' of undefined

I really don't know which may be the problem ???

```
function locurilibere(data, callback) {
var URL = Path + 'rezervaribilete/locurilibere/' + data;
$.get(URL, function(obj) {
if (obj.raspuns === "nu") {
callback(true);
} else {
callback(false);
}
}, 'json');
}

function populateCurseDus(de_la, pana_la, data_plecarii) {
var data = de_la + "-" + pana_la + "-" + data_plecarii;
$.get(Path + 'rezervaribilete/listCurseDus/' + data, function(o) {
for (var i = 0; i < o.length; i++) {
var id_cursa = o[i].id_cursa;
var datalocuri = id_cursa + "-" + data_plecarii;
locurilibere(datalocuri, function(result){
if (result) {
$('#cursedus tbody').append('<tr style="background:red;"><td><input type="radio" name="id_cursadus" value="' + o[i].id_cursa + '" disabled></td><td>' + o[i].cod_cursa + '</td><td>' + o[i].de_la + '</td><td>' + o[i].pana_la + '</td><td>' + o[i].ora_plecare + '</td><td>' + o[i].ora_sosire + '</td><td>' + o[i].id_transportator + '</td><td>' + o[i].id_traseu + '</td></tr>');
} else {
$('#cursedus tbody').append('<tr><td><input type="radio" name="id_cursadus" value="' + o[i].id_cursa + '"></td><td>' + o[i].cod_cursa + '</td><td>' + o[i].de_la + '</td><td>' + o[i].pana_la + '</td><td>' + o[i].ora_plecare + '</td><td>' + o[i].ora_sosire + '</td><td>' + o[i].id_transportator + '</td><td>' + o[i].id_traseu + '</td></tr>');
}
});
}
}, 'json');
}
```

Comment: Change the spot to a buttonhook, then post the code so we can have a hope of helping.

Comment: Is the second function always called _after_ the first? Please post your code.

Comment: How do you expect anyone to help you without seeing any code at all?

Comment: All I can say without code is that you should be returning `true` and `false` boolean values instead of "yes" and "no" strings.

Comment: Code added, I tried to find the bug of over 3-4 hours and no success. Ignore //

Comment: where is the error occurring, looks like some portion of the code is missing

Comment: How are those two functions called? Neither calls the other. (And "Ignore //"? Seriously? Please edit and remove things we are supposed to ignore.)

Comment: The first function returns if there are any free seats. I want to use the returning value in the second function to disable the flights (inputs) where there are no seats. The first function do what it has to do. It returns me the correct value from database, the thing is that when I am trying to use the first function in the second function to get the value in console log I get UNDEFINED ....

Comment: You're not actually returning anything from the first function. You're returning from inside the anonymous function (in the `$.get` call). `$.get` is asynchronous, so it actually doesn't execute the callback until later.

Comment: it will not work as you expected because you are making an ajax request in the first method, which is asynchronous in nature

Comment: code update , same problem , undefined

Comment: @NedeAdrian did you try my answer

Comment: @ Arun P Johny, I am now trying to implement it.

Comment: @Arun Johny : It was little hard to translate all stuff, because I am working on this homework in my native language. I am now trying to fix the problems and implement it

Comment: Your updated code still does not return a value from the `freeseats()` function. you have return statements inside the anonymous function that is _inside_ that first function, but those values are not returned from `freeseats()`.

Comment: @ArunPJohny I've updated the post with the code. New error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id_cursa' of undefined

Comment: @nnnnnn take a look over the new code ??? what is the problem now :-?? I really don't get it

Comment: @NedeAdrian it is because of the closure property `i`, try the update

Comment: @ArunPJohny just few moments.

Comment: @ArunPJohny you're the boss, it Works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not work as expected because of asynchronous nature of ajax request, you a callback to fix it

```
function freeseats(data, callback) {
    var URL = Path + 'bookings/freeseats/' + data;
    $.get(URL, function(obj) {
        if (obj.raspuns === "nu") {
            // alert("no");
            callback(true);
        } else {
            // alert("yes");
            callback(false);
        }
    }, 'json');
}

// ********************************* second
// **************************************
function populateDepartures(from, to, departure) {
    var data = from + "-" + to + "-" + departure;
    $.get(Path + 'booking/listDepartures/' + data, function(o) {

        $.each(o, function(index, item) {
            var id_flight = item.id_flight;
            var dataseats = id_flight + "-" + departureDate;

            freeseats(dataseats, function(result) {
                if (result) {
                    alert("no more seats");
                    $('#cursedus tbody')
                    .append('<tr style="background:red;"><td><input type="radio"         name="id_cursadus" value="'
                            + item.id_cursa
                            + '" disabled></td><td>'
                            + item.cod_cursa
                            + '</td><td>'
                            + item.de_la
                            + '</td><td>'
                            + item.pana_la
                            + '</td><td>'
                            + item.ora_plecare
                            + '</td><td>'
                            + item.ora_sosire
                            + '</td><td>'
                            + item.id_transportator
                            + '</td><td>'
                            + item.id_traseu + '</td></tr>');
                } else {
                    alert("there are free seats");
                    $('#cursedus tbody')
                    .append('<tr><td><input type="radio" name="id_cursadus" value="'
                            + item.id_cursa
                            + '"></td><td>'
                            + item.cod_cursa
                            + '</td><td>'
                            + item.de_la
                            + '</td><td>'
                            + item.pana_la
                            + '</td><td>'
                            + item.ora_plecare
                            + '</td><td>'
                            + item.ora_sosire
                            + '</td><td>'
                            + item.id_transportator
                            + '</td><td>'
                            + item.id_traseu + '</td></tr>');
                }
            });
        });
    }, 'json');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think I have deciphered what you need. Please take a look at this [jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/KevinIsNowOnline/67yNC/) and see if this serves your question.

Here's the code:

```
var boolFlag = false;
var firstFunc = function (){
    if(boolFlag === false){
        boolFlag = true;
        return 'yes';    
     }else{
        boolFlag = false;
        return 'no';   
    }
};


var secondFunc = function () {
        return firstFunc();
};

$('#myButton').click(function (){
    if(secondFunc() == 'yes'){
        console.log('hello world, you said: YES'); 
    }else{
        console.log('hello universe, you said: NO'); 
    }

});
```